# Does Hinduism forbid sexual intercourse before marriage?

Tags: scripture, belief, culture, marriage, sex

Well, I think the Indian society is very orthodox and can't generally accept things like an unmarried girl walking with or talking to a boy.

So is an unmarried girl or boy having sexual intercourse considered bad? Does Hinduism prohibit doing so?

It will be great if you can add some scriptural references to your answer.

Comment: When the saastras recommend the marriage of a boy and girl before their puberty, where does this question raise? When we violated the recommendation, we have to find the answer amongst ourselves and should not find in the saastras. Just adding some food for the thought and not with an intent to criticize the posters.

Comment: @Narayanan Where does Hindu scripture recommend marriage before puberty?  It certainly allows it, but I don't know of any scriptures that say that that's the preferred time of marriage.

Comment: I don't know the reference. I even seen the vaidheeka families do marriages this way even today.  Also, this is what I have understood as well. To support this, I only have one information: a performance called ritu shanthi is done after marriages these days and as a explanation, I was told that when the couples were married before puberty, the girl will attain that state after marriage and this ritu shanthi is done then.

Comment: @Narayanan Yeah, it's certainly a permitted practice, I just don't know of any scripture that discourages people from waiting until after puberty to get married.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, yourself have quoted manusmriti verses on marriagable age of girl. Ritu-shanti is not just a permitted practice, but a recommended one. Nowadays, people don't follow it, in fact they think people who follow it are weird. That is kali kaalam.

Comment: Shastras says one who is not performing prescribed duties and immoral they should be deemed as animal in human form so for animals no shastras apply in Valli case Valli asks to Rama same thing why did kill a monkey by applying human laws

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**TL;DR**: May or may not be permitted for Kshatriyas, but forbidden for everyone else, and not encouraged for Kshatriyas either.

Technically there is no such thing as *premarital* intercourse in Hinduism.  Whenever two people consummate a relationship, regardless of the circumstances, it is usually classified as a marriage of one sort or another.  It's even considered a marriage if the woman doesn't consent, like if she's drugged or unconscious.  The only question is whether it is a good marriage or a bad marriage, a marriage sanctioned by Hinduism or one that's strictly forbidden.

[This chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu03.htm) from the Manu Smriti describes the different kinds of marriage, which ones are permitted for which castes, and the consequences of doing one marriage vs. the other.

Here is the description of the eight types of marriage:

> [1.]  The gift of a daughter, after decking her (with costly garments) and honouring (her by presents of jewels), to a man learned in the Veda and of good conduct, whom (the father) himself invites, is called the Brahma rite.
>
> [2.]  The gift of a daughter who has been decked with ornaments, to a priest who duly officiates at a sacrifice, during the course of its performance, they call the Daiva rite.
>
> [3.]  When (the father) gives away his daughter according to the rule, after receiving from the bridegroom, for (the fulfilment of) the sacred law, a cow and a bull or two pairs, that is named the Arsha rite.
>
> [4.]  The gift of a daughter (by her father) after he has addressed (the couple) with the text, 'May both of you perform together your duties,' and has shown honour (to the bridegroom), is called in the Smriti the Pragapatya rite.
>
> [5.]  When (the bridegroom) receives a maiden, after having given as much wealth as he can afford, to the kinsmen and to the bride herself, according to his own will, that is called the Asura rite.
>
> **[6.]  The voluntary union of a maiden and her lover one must know (to be) the Gandharva rite, which springs from desire and has sexual intercourse for its purpose.**
>
> [7.]  The forcible abduction of a maiden from her home, while she cries out and weeps, after (her kinsmen) have been slain or wounded and (their houses) broken open, is called the Rakshasa rite.
>
> [8.]  When (a man) by stealth seduces a girl who is sleeping, intoxicated, or disordered in intellect, that is the eighth, the most base and sinful rite of the Pisakas.

So the sort of thing you're talking about would be classified as a Gandharva marriage.  Let's see what marriages are permitted for what castes:

> The sages state that the first four are approved (in the case) of a Brahmana, one, the Rakshasa (rite in the case) of a Kshatriya, and the Asura (marriage in that) of a Vaisya and of a Sudra.  But in these (Institutes of the sacred law) three of the five (last) are declared to be lawful and two unlawful; the Paisaka and the Asura (rites) must never be used.  For Kshatriyas those before-mentioned two rites, the Gandharva and the Rakshasa, whether separate or mixed, are permitted by the sacred tradition.

So "the sages", whoever they are, apparently say that the Gandharva marriage is forbidden for everyone, but the Manu Smriti is saying that they're wrong, and that a Gandharva marriage is actually permitted for Kshatriyas.

In any case, even if the Kshatriyas are allowed to have a Gandharva marriage, that doesn't mean that it's encouraged.  Marriages higher up on the list are still considered the best.

Comment: In Mahābhārata Ādi Parva 67, King Duhšānta also mentions eight kinds of marriages, when he wants to union with Šakuntala in the absence of her guardian sage Kanva. He concludes that they are both kšatriyas and a Gandharva rite is appropriate for them.

Comment: @MKaama Well, he does say it's allowed for them, but he also says that Manu "hath spoken of the appropriateness of all these forms according to their order", so Brahma marriage or Deva marriage would still be preferable to Gandharva marriage.

Comment: Nice post. But It spawns so many issues in today's society. When the 1st 2 rights are forced to be practiced by girl's father, it becomes **dowry**! 3 & 5 are like reverse of it. There is no mention that only 1 caste is allowed Gandharva rite. No.8 seems to be depicted in many movies so far.

Comment: @iammilind Thanks for the kind words!  "But It spawns so many issues in today's society. When the 1st 2 rights are forced to be practiced by girl's father, it becomes dowry!" Well, I think thats the wrong attitude to take.  We shouldnt judge Hindu scripture by whether it conforms with the modern sensibilities. Instead, we should use Hindu scripture as a guide to how to live our life, and we should use that as the standard to evaluate the correctness of modern sensibilities. In any case, I dont see anything wrong with a bridegroom saying he wont agree to a marriage unless it's a Brahma marriage

Comment: @iammilind Now if a bridegroom were to insist on a Brahma marriage simply for monetary reasons, as opposed to believing in the religious value of Brahma marriages, the problem with that wouldn't be that the father is paying money to the bridegroom.  Rather, the problem with that is that you shouldn't have monetary gain as your goal in life, you should value higher things, like dharma.

Comment: My whole point is, since in first 2 rites girl's father is the giver it should happen by choice; not the force by groom's family or society, else it creates today's nuisance like dowry. Not that first 2 rites are best for all, it depends on human type. Dowry as such may not be as notorious as projected, but it garners bad name when people who actually should have gone for other 6 rites, insist for first 2 rites. e.g. Live-In relation supporters better choose rite-6, as it is more suitable. Middle class better choose 4 and so on.

Comment: @iammilind I think Brahma marriage is best for all Dvijas.  One should not choose what type of marriage to have based on what is convenient or economical.  We should try to engage in the holiest marriage possible.  It is better to sacrifice the material for the sake of the spiritual.

Comment: Isn't Brahma marriage is obsolete nowadays ? Since, many grooms are NOT learned in Veda's ?

Comment: @Utkarsh Well, if you have a daughter, what Hinduism advises you to do is find a groom who is learned in the Vedas. You're right, lots of grooms nowadays haven't studied the Vedas, but for better or worse priests no longer check whether the groom has studied the Vedas or not; they just perform a Brahma marriage regardless, as long as the groom is wearing the sacred thread, because the sacred thread signifies eligibility to study the Vedas.  Unfortunately, a lot of grooms do the sacred thread ceremony the day before the wedding, so they don't devote any time to Vedic study.

Comment: Why is Rakshasa marrige or RAPE is allowed for kshatriyas?!!! This is no longer human rite, how can one justify forcible marrige?!! What will be krishna rukmini marrige considered as?.

Comment: @Yogi Krishna and Rukmini are sometimes considered to have had a Rakshasa marriage, and that's certainly what Rukmini's family thought it was, but technically it wasn't, because Rukmini was a willing participant in her own "kidnapping": http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/333/36 But as far as I can tell, Krishna actually kidnapped Lakshmana: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7861/36 Also, Bhishma kidnapped Amba, Ambika, and Ambalika.  In any case, perhaps you should post a question on whether Hindu scripture discusses why it's morally justified for a Kshatriya to do Rakashasa marriage.

Comment: @Yogi In any case, even though Kshatriyas are allowed to do Rakshasa marriages, it's still better if they do marriages that are higher on the list, ideally the Brahma marriage.

Comment: [@KeshavSrinivasan](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/36/keshav-srinivasan) / [@iammilind](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/1049/iammilind): What is the justification for this ordering? When is it considered appropriate to choose a lower-ranked rite over an upper-ranked one? Why is it holiest to give away a daughter along with a dowry?

Comment: So reading the 8th one I have a question.  Is there 8th one really a marriage because it states it is also a sin.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan The Rakshasa rite appears to be most base and sinful, especially because killing of kinsmen is involved. Why is Pisakas the most base and sinful instead?

Comment: @William That is why I said "Whenever two people consummate a relationship, regardless of the circumstances, it is usually classified as a marriage of one sort or another. It's even considered a marriage if the woman doesn't consent, like if she's drugged or unconscious. The only question is whether it is a good marriage or a bad marriage, a marriage sanctioned by Hinduism or one that's strictly forbidden."

Comment: @Harry Well, a Rakshasa marriage can be considered an act of bravery when done by a king; he announces his attentions, openly fights those who would oppose him, etc.  Whereas a Pishacha marriage is an act of deception.

Answer (score 19):

Yes,  [Manusmriti](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu11.htm)  forbids sexual intercourse with a virgin girl (without marriage). It consists provisions for the atonement of this sin.

> Carnal intercourse with sisters by the same mother, **with (unmarried) maidens**, with females of the lowest castes, with the wives of a friend, or of a son, they declare to be equal to the violation of a Guru's bed.[59]
>
> He who has had sexual intercourse with sisters by the same mother, with the wives of a friend, or of a son, **with unmarried maidens**, and with females of the lowest castes, shall perform the penance, prescribed for the violation of a Guru's bed.[171]

Answer (score 15):

Apart from the verse found in Triyugi Narayan Mani's answer above there is another verse in the Manu Smriti that clearly condemns pre-marital sex.

It is said that only virgins are fit for marriages:

> 8.226. **The nuptial texts are applied solely to virgins**, (and) nowhere among men to females **who have lost their virginity, for such (females)
>   are excluded from religious ceremonies.**

[image]

The Parashara Smriti declares that unmarried maidens(Kumari) becoming mothers are traits of Kali Yuga ,when Adharma(irreligion) will overthrow Dharma(religion).

> 30 & 31. "Religion has been overthrown by irreligion ; and truth
>   indeed by that which is false ; kings have been overpowered by thieves
>   ; males have been subdued by females ; the worship of fire is dying
>   out ; respect to superiors is ceasing to be seen ; **and maidens are
>   becoming mothers : this is what invariably happens in the age of Kali**.

[image]

Comment: I'm waiting for [wisdomlib.org](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi) to post their full tr. of Manu w/ commentary. But it appears that in 8.226 Manu is only talking about female virgins? What about men who lost their virginity?

Comment: Men defiling maidens are mentioned in many places as sin in Manu..apart from that i have not found anything specially in regards of marriage of men who lost their virginity..But since a man and woman lose virginity together so both are condemned i guess...

Comment: @sv. 8.226 is not only talking about females. It clearly states among "men to females". It is strange however that the next part of the sentence only focuses on females.