# In which war of devas and asuras did Yaduvamsis participate?

Tags: war, yadavas

[This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/27857/12304) answer says

> The mythology says after the destruction of the Yaduvamsis in the course of the devasura sangrama several thousand wives of Lord Krishna were abducted...

Now, my questions are

Scriptures (like [Mahabharata](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m16/m16001.htm), [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/30)) mention different story of the destruction of Yadavas. Is this story of the destruction of the Yaduvamsis in the course of the devasura sangrama (war of devas and asuras) valid? If yes then,

In which war did the Yadavas participate?

Why did this war happen?

Which side did Yadavas fight for? Is it devas or asuras?