# Fairness of pre-marital relation based on that of Satyavati and Parashara

Tags: mahabharata, marriage

Why did Satyavati and Parashara have a child out of wedlock?
Why did she then marry Shantanu?
Based on this, does it mean pre-martial relationship is fair?
Was their relationship really bodily, because he was a great sage how could he lust someone?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the view of Hinduism on prostitution and premarital sex?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16103/whats-the-view-of-hinduism-on-prostitution-and-premarital-sex)

Comment: These incidents in Mahabharat do not involve normal human beings. Can you imagine any common man/woman having sex, and a child being born that is instantly 16 years old (Vyasa), or born with an armor and earrings (Karna) ? You have to stop seeing the acts of Avataras through human eyes/mind.

Comment: No I'm not seeing it through human eyes, but those women were humans and they were married to a human.

Comment: @Rahul - are you sure they were humans ? can a human have a child who is 16 years old at birth ? can a human have a child born with armor and earrings ?

Comment: So sathyavathi and Kunti mata were not human's. But they were married to a human later, what about that. I'm not thinking bad things about them, but I feel like are those people who stands against dharma having a point. If I'm wrong please correct me.