# Is underage sex for pleasure considered bad?

Tags: belief, dharma, sin, dharma-shastras, sex

Do Hindu scriptures consider engaging in sex for pleasure an evil malpractice when the persons involved are juvenile?

If not, why does the orthodox Indian/Hindu community believe so?

Comment: Related [Does Hinduism forbid sexual intercourse before marriage?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/916/3500).

Comment: That question is marriage centric. My question in age centric. I can term a case that one may marry before his puberty for sexual pleasures. But will his motive be considered sinful?

Comment: @AniruddhaSarkar No, sexual intercourse before puberty is prohibited in Hinduism