# According to Smriti Shastras, what punishment is prescribed for a girl who lost virginity before marriage?

Tags: manu-smriti, smriti, sex, parashara-smriti, virginity

I suppose Smriti Shastras do not encourage sex before marriage. But these days, it is pretty common. I want to know the views of Smriti Shastras on it. What kind of punishment is prescribed for girls?

Manu Smriti Verse 8.226 says that the girl can not marry following the Vedic ritual. But apart from that ban, is there any specific punishment she is supposed to receive? For example, Manu says as a punishment for having sex with Guru's wife, the disciple has to cut off his penis and testicles (Manu Smrti 11.105). I want to know whether such strict punishment is prescribed for girls who lost virginity before the marriage.

Comment: **As per the scriptures** - 1): The girl must be married before she reaches puberty lest the father incurs a big Sin. 2): As per [THIS ANSWER](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/916/does-hinduism-forbid-sexual-intercourse-before-marriage/924#924) - "*Technically there is no such thing as premarital intercourse in Hinduism. Whenever two people consummate a relationship, regardless of the circumstances, it is usually classified as a marriage of one sort or another. **It's even considered a marriage if the woman doesn't consent,** like if she's drugged or unconscious.*"

Comment: So one may be able to guess - the kind of incomprehensible justifications some people give for some "incomprehensible-acts" **might** be derived from Scriptures (or "wrongly-interpreted").

Comment: @Vivikta 2nd is not encouraged by Rishis. Moreover, smritis say menstrual cycle clears such things (sex without consent; rape.). indeed, menstruation clears minor sins committed by women unknowingly.

Comment: Yes, indeed true: @TheDestroyer - that it's **not encouraged**. **However, the very premise of the question is** - *"The intercourse has been done (either via consent or non-consensual)"*. And for that, the answer is already given & Justified by the Scriptures i.e., *"Regardless of consent or not, premarital sex between a male & female, is to be taken as a Marriage only"*. Now, that's a side addition if that kind of marriage is worse than the other "top-four marriages" or if the women are naturally cleared of sins aftr menses; **In any case  - "*Premarital sex in any form=Marriage*".**

Comment: @TheDestroyer can you please mention the verse number that says menstrual cycle clears minor sin?

Comment: Vasishta Dharma Sutra V. 4-5 & Baudhayana Dharma Sutra 2.2.4.4

Comment: @Vivikta I found the Baudhayana verse. thanks. But Vashisth reference is not right, I think.